# closed form expression for the sum of the first s items of alternating binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Is there a closed form expression for the following sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^s (-1)^k {n \choose k}, $$

where $s \in \{0,1,2,...,n\}$

-- which is basically the first $s$ terms in the alternating binomial coefficients
series.   I know if $s=n$, the sum is zero, but I cannot figure out a general closed form expression in terms of $s$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncated alternating binomial sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887960/truncated-alternating-binomial-sum)

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is:
$$(-1)^s {n-1 \choose s}$$

Proof by induction, for example, is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, the formula works - but how do you get the formula?

Comment: @Argonne Are you asking (a) how do you prove it given what it is, or (b) how would you go about finding out what it is if you didn't know?