# Can we have a closed form or approximation of following combination summation?Or when it is positive or not?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Can we have any closed form or approximation of the summation? And can we know when it is positive?

$S(n,t)=\sum_{i=0}^{t}(-1)^{i}\tbinom{n}{i}$

We can assume that $0<t<n/2$.

This is the sum of the $D(n,t)=\tbinom{n}{t}-\tbinom{n}{t+1}$.  A simpler form of $D(n,t)$ may help the problem.

Till now, I can not find any help from Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Did you mean Stirling’s Approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Partial_sums) that your sum $S(n,t) = (-1)^t \binom{n-1}{t}$. There are a variety of proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887960/truncated-alternating-binomial-sum) for instance. Among other things, this means that the sum is nonnegative if and only if $t$ is even.

As for asymptotics, there are lots of known approximations for $\binom{n-1}{t}$ which depend on how quickly $t$ and $n$ are growing. One useful set of bounds is

$$
\frac{n^k}{k^k} \leq \binom{n}{k} \leq \frac{n^k}{k!}
$$

Which one can easily use to approximate $S(n,t) = (-1)^t \binom{n-1}{t}$.

Asymptotically, one can use [stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to obtain the sharpest result which is always true as follows:

First expand the definition of the closed form of $S(n,t)$:

$$S(n,t) = (-1)^t \binom{n-1}{t} = (-1)^t \frac{(n-1)!}{t!(n-1-t)!}$$

Then apply the stirling approximation:

$$
(-1)^t \frac{(n-1)!}{t!(n-1-t)!} \sim
(-1)^t \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi (n-1)}(n-1)^{n-1}/e^{n-1}}{\left ( \sqrt{2 \pi t} t^t / e^t \right ) \left ( \sqrt{2 \pi (n-1-t)} (n-1-t)^{n-1-t}/e^{n-1-t}\right )}
$$

Now you can cancel and simplify this to

$$
(-1)^t \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{2 \pi t (n-1-t)}} \frac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{t^t (n-1-t)^{n-1-t}}
$$

This expression, while correct, is slightly unwieldy. If you know more information about how $t$ grows (for instance, is $t \approx \sqrt{n}$? $kn$? $n^{0.1}$?) you can simplify the above expression (sometimes dramatically). Google has lots of results in this vein.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks for your help! I also prove  the closed form $S(n,t) = (-1)^t \binom{n-1}{t}$ myself.

Comment: That's great! ^_^. Also, if this answered your question you should mark it as such. This way other users know how to spend their time

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I clicked an "accept" button(√) on the left of your answer. Is this "mark" OK?