# Connection between probability and finite cardinality for Bonferroni inequalities

Tags: probability, upper-lower-bounds, inclusion-exclusion

Let

$$S_1=\sum_i|A_i|, \quad S_2= \sum_{i<j}|A_i \cap A_j|, \quad S_3=\sum_{i<j<k} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| ,\quad \cdots$$

Define alternating partial sums
$$R_1 = S_1,\quad R_2 = S_1 - S_2, \quad R_3 = S_1 - S_2 + S_3,\quad \cdots $$

I've long believed but never seen explicitly union bound / Bonferroni-type inequalities for finite cardinality sets:

$$R_2 \le R_4 \le \cdots \le \left|\bigcup_i A_i \right| \le \cdots \le R_3 \le R_1 $$

Can these be proved from the probability formulation? $|A_i \cup A_j| \le |A_i| + |A_j|$ just as $P(A_i \cup A_j) \le P(A_i) + P(A_j)$. My idea was define a discrete uniform distribution $U[1,n]$. Let $B_i$ be subsets of the domain and $A_i = x \in B_i$ for $x \sim U[1,n]$. Then $P(A_i) = |B_i|/n$ (I'm not sure if this notation is correct). Scaling by $n$, this should give the above bounds? Actually, can this be proved from first principles just using induction on inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: Yes, the set-cardinality version follows from the probability formulation, using $\text{Unif}[1,n]$. Yes, you can prove this from first principles using induction, as I showed [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4492445/177399). The other answers at that link give other proofs, which are slicker than mine.

Comment: More proofs of the Bonferroni inequalities here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208766/how-to-prove-bonferroni-inequalities/

Comment: @MikeEarnest can you turn this comment into an answer? I'm still not sure on my usage of events and sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know how to prove $R_{2n}\le |\bigcup A_i|\le R_{2n-1}$ for each $n\ge 1$, but I do not know how to prove $R_2\le R_4\le \dots \le R_3\le R_1$.

Let $\Omega$ be a set containing $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. If you choose an element $\omega$ from $\Omega$ uniformly at random, the probability that $\omega\in A_i$ is $|A_i|/|\Omega|$. Now, let $E_i$ be the event that $\omega\in A_i$. If you take the inequalities you want to prove and multiply through by $1/|\Omega|$, then the result is exactly the same thing, where all sets $A_i$ are replaced with events $E_i$ and all cardinalities $|\cdot|$ are replaced with probabilities. Therefore, the probabilistic Bonferroni inequalities imply the set-based ones, and vice versa.

There are some slick proofs of the Bonferroni inequalities at [How to prove Bonferroni inequalities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208766/how-to-prove-bonferroni-inequalities/)
and [Overestimates and underestimates in Inclusion-Exclusion principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4490765/overestimates-and-underestimates-in-inclusion-exclusion-principle), including some inductive proofs from first principles.

Comment: I like your formulation better because you started with given $A_i$'s instead of what I did which strictly speaking only applies to subsets of [1,n].

Comment: Does $\Omega$ need to be finite? It can be given all the $A_i$ are.

Comment: $\Omega$ can be infinite.